# Track use of send dialog

Tags: facebook

I'm using the Fb.ui send dialog to hopefully allow users to connect to other users.  I want to know if there is anyway to track the use of this dialog box so I can tell if users are taking advantages of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could track the usage of the send dialog by putting in some simple tracking at 3 different stages

1. User clicks on your 'send message' button to open the dialog
2. User opens the dialog but clicks cancel
3. User opens the dialog and then sends a message

Here's some sample code demoing how you can add a callback to the send dialog and determine whether or not the user actually sent a message. Although please note that there seems to be some issues with this at the moment and I'm not totally sure that the send dialog supports callbacks fully yet.

```
FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'Google',
          link: 'http://www.google.com',
      }, 
     function(response) {
        if (response) {
            // user sent the message
        } else {
            // user clicked cancel
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a difference between the Send Dialog and the Send Button? I'm interested in doing some tracking on the Send Button (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/); is it possible to instantiate a send button form the JS API?

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function, trigger an ajax call to a php script that will recored the call in the database.
This way you'll know how many time the dialog was used, and by which user.